# Leaflet printing does not show pins and map is shifted

Tags: javascript, printing, leaflet, gis

I don't exactly why but whenever I try to print my leaflet map with layers, it shows the map a little shifted to the left as well as the pins are not quite ok. I tried using `easyPrint()` and `window.print()`, same result. It used to work well. Any ideas? Here is the difference

[image: how it should look]

when it opens up to print the map
[image: how it looks]

Using easyprint, (I am importing easyprint's css)

```
jQuery.print.js:125 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8001/proj/easyPrint.css  
 $.print.$.fn.print @ jQuery.print.js:125
 (anonymous function) @ VM4317:1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the `Easyprint.css` .

Remove this line:

```
.leaflet-control-easyPrint-button{display: none!important;}
```

Comment: Hi HudsonPH, thanks you for help. I tried changing it but it didn't make any difference. I edited and added some more details on what it is saying in the browser's log.

Comment: you need check if this pieces are backgroud if yes put !important in the final, like:   
" background-image: url(../Images/layers.png) !important; "

Comment: and internet explorer just print background if you enable in the print setup.